# Find a determinant for a linear map $Z \in M_{7×7}(\mathbb R)$ if you know that $Z^{2}-8Z^{-1}$ is a zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a trouble with this task because I think that I need clever way to do this easy and fast.
 However I don't have any idea to don't count it.  My only idea is to firstly calculate $Z^{2}$ but then I will have a lot of parameters because I don't have knowledge about $Z$ and I think this idea is impossible to make. 
How do it in intelligent way?

Comment: $Z^2=8Z^{-1}$ hence the determinant satisfies the equation $x^2 = 8^7/x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $Z^3=8I$, so $(\det Z)^3 = 8^7$. Hence $\det Z = 2^7$.

Comment: How you get to the power of $7$?

Comment: In $M_{7 \times 7}$, $8I$ is a matrix with all off-diagonal elements equal to $0$ and all (seven) diagonal elements equal to $8$. Its determinant is the product of the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0):

Then $Z^3=8I$, so $Z$ is diagonalisable, and its eigenvalues are in the set
$\{2,2\omega,2\omega^2\}$ where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$. The determinant of
$Z$ is a product of seven of these, and is real....